# htaccess redirect fails with multiple URL parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect to remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect to "page" for dynamic pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page?url=/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

This allows my custom CMS to use dynamic URLs (http://example.com/some-page, for example) and redirect it to http://example.com/page?url=some-page so that the CMS can render the content.  It all works great - until someone adds a URL like http://example.com/something/else.  When I spit out the url parameter with: `print $_GET['url'];` I get `/something/else.php/else`.

So it seems like the remove .php directive is getting lost and the second parameter is getting duplicated? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could removeing the .php from the string be a solution?

Comment: The first rule should be doing that - and I know that one works as I've got a few static pages that display fine (without the .php).

Comment: "`page?url=/$1 [L]`" - Shouldn't that be `page.php`? (Otherwise, you are relying on mod_rewrite to add the extension later with another rewrite.)

Comment: Hmm, tried that as well, no luck - same problem.

Comment: (That wasn't intended as a solution, but it avoids an unnecessary rewrite.) Is `/something` a physical directory, or entirely virtual? Does `/something/else.php` exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect to remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Redirect to "page" for dynamic pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule !^page\.php$ page.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,QSA]
```

Here are changes:

1. Keep redirect rule before rewrite rules otherwise when `www` is removed from a URL then your internal URL will be exposed.
2. Use `page.php` in target instead of `page` to avoid another rewrite rule execution.
3. Use `[L]` flag in `.php` adding rule.
4. Addition of `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: Unfortunately that throws a 500 internal server error - but only on pages with multiple URL parameters (/something/else).  Pages with a simple /something URL are fine.

Comment: Same problem - page.php is in site root (/public_html/page.php).

Comment: Yes, just did that - looks like the error is "AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: Done, same problem unfortunately. There are some subdirectories in the site but page.php is in root.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151111/discussion-between-anubhava-and-sean-cunningham).